# C/C++/C#: how to force repaint of window chrome on windows 7?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-7, window-chrome

My application has a standard top level window for the application. I need to force a repaint of the window chrome (otherwise known as the non-client area of the window). I do not care if the client area is also repainted or not but the chrome itself needs to be forced to repaint.

In particular I need this to work on Windows 7. Whether it works on other OS versions does not matter in my particular case. The solution can be C, C++, C# or any other language.

Comment: i would think that windows would paint the chrome on its own. whats the scenario in which windows is misbehaving?

Comment: Does this.Invalidate() not update the chrome? I can't think of a quick/easy test to try it myself....

Comment: overslacked: Invalidate() causes redrawing of the client area but not the window chrome. 

obelix: The issue is a complicated one. Under Windows 7 (but not others) a new modal window that has custom chrome drawing using WM_NCPAINT occasionally does not draw anything. Mostly it works fine and then 1 in 50 times nothing, as if the window is not there at all. If I can detect when this occurs I would like to force redraw of the entire window hoping it will then appear. I have tried repainting the client and that did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911(VS.85).aspx), it seems that

```
RedrawWindow( hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_FRAME );
```

is what you are looking for.

> RDW_FRAME causes any part of the nonclient area of the window that intersects the update region to receive a WM_NCPAINT message. The RDW_INVALIDATE flag must also be specified; otherwise, RDW_FRAME has no effect. The WM_NCPAINT message is typically not sent during the execution of RedrawWindow unless either RDW_UPDATENOW or RDW_ERASENOW is specified.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you could send the WM_NCPAINT message to the window

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but this message is sent by the operating system when it has already decided it needs to have the window painted. Sending this message to the window will not cause the chrome to be updated on the screen but merely get the code to draw into a DC that I would have to supply myself.